# Inlfuxdb Retention policy being activated incorrectly

Tags: influxdb

I have a Influxdb database that is losing data due the activation of the retention policy.

I upgraded the influxdb code from the v1.6.3 to v1.7.7, but the behavior is the same.

```
> SHOW RETENTION POLICIES ON "telegraf"
name    duration shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----    -------- ------------------ -------- -------
autogen 0s       168h0m0s           1        false
forever 0s       168h0m0s           1        true
```

```
Aug 16 06:02:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T09:02:25.623073Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HIQTFLW000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=start
Aug 16 06:02:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T09:02:25.623477Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HIQTFLW000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=end op_elapsed=0.487ms
Aug 16 06:32:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T09:32:25.623033Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HISB6aW000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=start
Aug 16 06:32:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T09:32:25.623339Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HISB6aW000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=end op_elapsed=0.352ms
Aug 16 07:02:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T10:02:25.622970Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HITtyqW000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=start
Aug 16 07:02:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T10:02:25.623272Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HITtyqW000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=end op_elapsed=0.362ms
Aug 16 07:32:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T10:32:25.622899Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HIVbq5W000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=start
Aug 16 07:32:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T10:32:25.623780Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HIVbq5W000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=end op_elapsed=0.917ms
Aug 16 08:02:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T11:02:25.622839Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HIXKhLW000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=start
Aug 16 08:02:25 influxdb influxd[805]: ts=2019-08-16T11:02:25.622987Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" log_id=0HEpQh70000 service=retention trace_id=0HIXKhLW000 op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=end op_elapsed=0.171ms
```

I should not see the retention policy being activated ever, as the duration is set to '0s'. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want forever retention policy to stay just write following query to influx.

`> DROP RETENTION POLICY "forever" ON "telegraf"`

And make autogen retention policy as default for telegraf database.

`> ALTER RETENTION POLICY "autogen" ON "telegraf" DEFAULT`